# If product is multiple of a number what information can we draw?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, gcd-and-lcm, products

If a product is a multiple of $4$, I conclude that one of the numbers is a multiple of $2$ the following way:
If $$ab \equiv0\pmod 4$$ then $$ab = 4X = 2(2X) = 2Y$$ (where $Y = 2X$)
This implies that either $a$ or $b$ is a multiple of $2$ so $a$ or $b$ is even.

My question is if this approach is correct or there is a more "formal" way to do it.
Additionally what other conclusions can we draw by knowing that $ab$ is a multiple of $4$?

Comment: $4|ab\implies 2|ab\implies 2|a$ or $2|b$ by [Euclid's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma)

Comment: It's correct / complete only if you justify the claim that $\,2\mid ab\Rightarrow 2\mid a\,$ or $\,2\mid b\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque: does that need proof? I thought it made sense

Comment: @BillDubuque: So the proof you mention is exactly Euclid's lemma?

Comment: What about `4`? Can we deduce anything about multiples of 4? Or only about 2?

Comment: Yes, it needs proof. Yes, the linked statement is one form of Eudlid's Lemma.  Applied again we can deduce that either both $a$ and $b$ are even or one of them is divisible by $4.\ \ $